# How to search string in large text file?

Tags: c#, search, streamreader

I want to get the line containing a certain word that cannot be repeated like profile ID without make loop to read each of line separately, Because if the word I am looking for is in the last line of the text file, this will take a lot of time to get it, and if the search process is for more than one word and extract the line that contains it, I think it will take a lot of time.

Example for line text file
name,id,image,age,place,link

```cs
string word = "13215646";
string output = string.Empty;
    
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(FileName))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    String line;
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] strList = line.Split(',');
        if (word == strList[1]) // check if word = id
        {
            output = line;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could limit the number of splits to 1 more than you require (e.g. `line.Split(',', 3);`) which will provide ["name", "id", "image,age,place,link"] as the resulting array. That would be a minor optimisation, though `.IndexOf` and `.Substring` would probably be better. As for how to avoid reading the entire file: you can't, unless you know the exact position in the file (not the exact line, the exact character) where you expect to find your value.

Comment: Do we use .IndexOf or .Substring ?

Comment: You can for the optimising checking an individual line, yes. But it's a microptimisation really. The larger portion of time will be spent reading the file, and you can't get around doing that. P.S. If you're asking "which one do I use": they both do different things, so that doesn't make sense as a question. `.IndexOf` will find the index of a character or string within another string, and `.Substring` allows you to take a section of a string using a start index and length.

Comment: best way is read each line and check it ?

Comment: "Best"? More like "the only way". Databases are smarter with this and have indexes, which allow them to quickly find information, but for a simple text file that's not really an option.

Comment: in my case i can`t use database

Comment: There you go then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to search the file:

```
var output = File.ReadLines(FileName).
    Where(line => line.Split(',')[1] == word).
    FirstOrDefault();
```

But it won't solve this:

> if the word I am looking for is in the last line of the text file, this will take a lot of time to get it, and if the search process is for more than one word and extract the line that contains it, I think it will take a lot of time.

**There's not a practical way to avoid this for a basic file.**

The only ways around actually reading through the file is either maintaining an index, which requires absolute control over everything that might write into the file, or if you can guarantee the file is already sorted by the columns that matter, in which case you can do something like a binary search.

But neither is likely for a random csv file. This is one of the reasons people use databases.

However, we also need to stop and check whether this is really a problem for you. I'd expect the code above to handle files up to a couple hundred MB in around 1 to 2 seconds on modern hardware, even if you need to look through the whole file.

Comment: but my code is good for this process ?!

Answer (score 1):

You can optimise the code. Here are few ideas:

```cs
var ids = new ["13215646", "113"];

foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(FileName))
{
    var id = line.Split(',', count: 3)[1]; // Optimization 1: Use: `count: 3`
    if(ids.Contains(id)                    // Optimization 2: Search for multiple ids 
    {
       //Do what you need with the line
    }
}
```

Comment: it will read each line then check